# combine 2 substr and 1 strpos in one line php

Tags: php, substr, strpos

My string $podcast->title returns something like this :

```
Artist Name - The Title
```

I'm using the following 2 lines of code :

```
$this_dj = substr($podcast->title, 0, strpos($podcast->title, "-"));
$this_dj = substr($this_dj, 0, -1);
```

The first line strips everything after (and including the "-") which leaves me with :

```
Artist Name
```

The second line removes the whitespace at the end.

My question is, can I combine these two lines into one line?

I've tried :

```
$this_dj = substr($podcast->title, 0, strpos($podcast->title, "-"), -1);
```

But that didn't work.

Comment: If you want to remove Whitespaces at the end, the best way to do so would be to use [`trim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php).

Comment: Would I just add that at the end?

Comment: like this: `trim(substr($podcast->title, 0, strpos($podcast->title, "-")));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would also work with your example, just move the substring end point:

```
$this_dj = substr($podcast->title, 0, strpos($podcast->title, "-") - 1);
```

Comment: Yes this worked, I was also including an extra comma. Thank you Siffer!

Answer (score 1):

If your delimiter is always constant you can use `explode`, it's much easier, see example below.

```
$string = 'Artist Name - The Title';

$array = explode(' - ', $string);

print_r($array);
```

Will output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Artist Name
    [1] => The Title
)
```

And using `list` you can populate variables directly

```
list($artist,$song) = explode(' - ', $string);

print $artist . PHP_EOL;
print $song . PHP_EOL;
```

Which will output

```
Artist Name
The Title
```

No whitespace :)

Comment: Although this strictly wasn't the answer to my question this is brilliant. I'm going to do it this way. I'll have to accept one of the other answers as they are more directly relevant to the question but thank you so much for this Alex!

Answer (score 1):

Use [trim()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) command:

```
$this_dj = trim(substr($podcast->title, 0, strpos($podcast->title, "-")));
```